# How to check buffer pool size in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, memory, sql, buffer

Is there any way to find total allocated buffer pool size in sql server.In mysql we can find it by using the variable innodb_buffer_pool_size.Is there any equivalent for that in sql server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find out how much buffer cache each database on the sql instance is using you could run this query which uses the dmv [`sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173442(v=sql.110).aspx):

```
SELECT
  database_id AS DatabaseID,
  DB_NAME(database_id) AS DatabaseName,
  COUNT(file_id) * 8/1024.0 AS BufferSizeInMB
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
GROUP BY DB_NAME(database_id),database_id
ORDER BY BufferSizeInMB DESC
GO
```